# VB.NET POST multiple files and parameters

Tags: vb.net, post, multipartform-data

I need to make a POST request to a server.
this request must have multiple parameters, like this :

- name
- number
- host

and multiples files

- file1
- file2
- file3

How can I do that in VB.NET. I tried `WebRequest` object, but there's no simple way to do that.

thanks

Comment: And what exactly did you try? Or what exactly problem you encounter?

Comment: I try to POST a multipart/form-data with multiple parameters, strings and files. `WebRequest` provide only a stream. There's no `AddParam` or `AddFile` methods.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check if it will work, but I would try something like:

```
' post request with some parameters inside query string
uriPath = String.Format("{0}{1}?func=xxx&uid={2}", url, fileName, id)
reqUri = New Uri(uriPath)
webReq = CType(WebRequest.Create(reqUri), HttpWebRequest)
webReq.Method = "Post"

' webReq.Timeout = 10000

webReq.KeepAlive = False
webReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

' HERE is a place to attach your files
' try to run it at loop for each file
form = "name=" & fileName
webReq.ContentLength = form.Length
Dim sw As New StreamWriter(webReq.GetRequestStream, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)
sw.Write(form)
' here write/send the file content
sw.Flush()
sw.Close()
sw.Dispose()

' reading response
Using res As WebResponse = webReq.GetResponse
    Dim st As Stream = res.GetResponseStream()
    Dim rd As New StreamReader(st)

    status = rd.ReadLine()
```

If I remember well POST request of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` type is sent
in form of:

```
--- params separator
name=fileName
file content
--- params separator
name=fileName1
file1 content
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Webclient instead :

For values :

```
' Create a value collection
Dim myNameValueCollection As New NameValueCollection()
' Set up POST variables
myNameValueCollection.Add("name", someName)
myNameValueCollection.Add("number", someNumber)
...
Using wc As New System.Net.WebClient()
    wc.UploadValues(remoteUrl, myNameValueCollection)
End Using
```

And for files simply :

```
Using wc As New System.Net.WebClient()
    wc.UploadFile(remoteUrl, yourfile)
End Using
```

Comment: and for files ? I can put byte[] in values ?

Comment: I updated the answer ,although you can't POST many files at once with this method.

Comment: ok, but for POST both `myNameValueCollection` and files in the same POST request ?